# Not able to Rotate my 3D objects

Tags: rotation, uigesturerecognizer, scenekit, arkit

I had created one project using ARKit and SceneKit framework. In which I am working with file extension .dae, the files are locally available in my project as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Here I had applied many gestures on this virtual object such as Tap Gesture(When I tap on camera screen, it places the virtual object there), same way Pinch Gesture and Pan Gesture. All of these gestures are working perfectly fine. Now I wanted to apply rotation gesture, for which I got stuck how to do that, also I am not getting any such available sources to achieve this.

Below is my working code so far,

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    private var movedObject: SCNNode?
    private var hud :MBProgressHUD!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene

        registerGestureRecognizers()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    private func registerGestureRecognizers() {

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(recognizer:)))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        let pinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinched(recognizer:)))
        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecognizer)

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveObject(recognizer:)))
        panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        let rotationGestureRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotateObject(recognizer:)))
        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func pinched(recognizer :UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

        if recognizer.state == .changed {

            guard let sceneView = recognizer.view as? ARSCNView else {
                return
            }
            let touch = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
            let hitTestResults = self.sceneView.hitTest(touch, options: nil)
            if let hitTest = hitTestResults.first {
                let chairNode = hitTest.node
                let pinchScaleX = Float(recognizer.scale) * chairNode.scale.x
                let pinchScaleY = Float(recognizer.scale) * chairNode.scale.y
                let pinchScaleZ = Float(recognizer.scale) * chairNode.scale.z
                chairNode.scale = SCNVector3(pinchScaleX,pinchScaleY,pinchScaleZ)
                recognizer.scale = 1
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func moveObject(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Move object")
        if recognizer.state == .began {
            print("Pan state began")
            let tapPoint: CGPoint? = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
            let result = sceneView.hitTest(tapPoint ?? CGPoint.zero, options: nil)
            if result.count == 0 {
                return
            }
            let hitResult: SCNHitTestResult? = result.first
            if (hitResult?.node.name == "free_car_1") {
                movedObject = hitResult?.node
            } else if (hitResult?.node.parent?.name == "free_car_1") {
                movedObject = hitResult?.node.parent
            }
            if (movedObject != nil) {
                print("Holding an Object")
            }
        }
        if recognizer.state == .changed {
            print("Pan State Changed")
            if (movedObject != nil) {
                let tapPoint: CGPoint? = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
                let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapPoint ?? CGPoint.zero, types: .featurePoint)
                let result: ARHitTestResult? = hitResults.last
                let matrix: SCNMatrix4 = SCNMatrix4((result?.worldTransform)!)
                //SCNMatrix4FromMat4((result?.worldTransform)!)
                let vector: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(matrix.m41, matrix.m42, matrix.m43)
                movedObject?.position = vector
                print("Moving object position")
            }
        }
        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            print("Done moving object homeie")
            movedObject = nil
        }
    }

    @objc func tapped(recognizer :UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        guard let sceneView = recognizer.view as? ARSCNView else {
            return
        }
        let touch = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
        let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(touch)
        guard let hitTest = hitTestResults.first?.node else {
            let hitTestResultsWithExistingPlane = sceneView.hitTest(touch, types: .existingPlane)
            let chairScene = SCNScene(named: "ShelbyWD.dae")!
            guard let chairNode = chairScene.rootNode.childNode(withName:       "ShelbyWD", recursively: true) else {
                return
            }
            if let hitTestAvailable = hitTestResultsWithExistingPlane.first {
                chairNode.position = SCNVector3(hitTestAvailable.worldTransform.columns.3.x,hitTestAvailable.worldTransform.columns.3.y,hitTestAvailable.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
                self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(chairNode)
                return
            }
            return
        }
        hitTest.removeFromParentNode()
    }

    @objc func rotateObject(recognizer :UIRotationGestureRecognizer) 
    {

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out to apply rotation gesture on my object?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to rotate an `SCNNode`, the 1st thing you need to do, is create a variable to store the rotationAngle around the YAxis or any other that you wish to perform the rotation on e.g:

```
var currentAngleY: Float = 0.0
```

Then have some way to have detected to node you wish to rotate, which in my example I am calling currentNode e.g.

```
var currentNode: SCNNode!
```

In my example I will just rotate around the YAxis.

You can use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` like so:

```
/// Rotates An Object On It's YAxis
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer
@objc func rotateObject(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let nodeToRotate = currentNode else { return }

    let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view!)
    var newAngleY = (Float)(translation.x)*(Float)(Double.pi)/180.0
    newAngleY += currentAngleY

    nodeToRotate.eulerAngles.y = newAngleY

    if(gesture.state == .ended) { currentAngleY = newAngleY }

    print(nodeToRotate.eulerAngles)
}
```

Or if you wish to use a `UIRotationGesture` you can do something like this:

```
/// Rotates An SCNNode Around It's YAxis
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer
@objc func rotateNode(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){

//1. Get The Current Rotation From The Gesture
let rotation = Float(gesture.rotation)

//2. If The Gesture State Has Changed Set The Nodes EulerAngles.y
if gesture.state == .changed{
    isRotating = true
    currentNode.eulerAngles.y = currentAngleY + rotation
}

//3. If The Gesture Has Ended Store The Last Angle Of The Cube
if(gesture.state == .ended) {
    currentAngleY = currentNode.eulerAngles.y
    isRotating = false
 }
}
```

Hope it helps...